# What are examples of functions that are $L^1$ but not $L^2$ and vice versa?

Tags: real-analysis

This exercise is in Stein's Real analysis.

> Find a function such that $f$ is $L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$, but not $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n)$
>
> Find a function such that $f$ is $L^2$ but not $L^1$.
>
> Hint: consider $f(x)=|x|^{-a}$ on $|x|<1$ or $|x|>1$.

I was trying to use the hind to fin such functions.

Let $f(x)=|x|^{-a}$ on $|x|<1$ and $f(x)=0$ otherwise.

Since it is radial, $\int |f|dm_n = m_n(B(0,1))\int_0^1x^{-a}x^{n-1} dx$.

Similarly $\int |f|^2dm_n = m_n(B(0,1))\int_0^1x^{-2a}x^{n-1} dx$.

I could!'t find suitable $a$ to make this $f$ to be a desired function..

Help..

Comment: You won't have any luck with a function with finite support, since $L^2(\mu) \subseteq L^1(\mu)$ for all finite measures $\mu$ (as a consequence of Holder's inequality).

Comment: @user61527 any suggestion then??

Comment: Well, the hint has two options for where $x$ lives. The first one doesn't work.

Comment: For $L^\text{small}$ but not $L^\text{big}$ you want to look at horizontally asymptotic behaviour.  The other way around, vertical asymptotes.

Comment: Your hint is just fine. The problem doesn't even require that your functions be continuous, which makes it even easier - just find functions that fail in sufficiently nice domains and make them 0 elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

Let $n=1$, let $f(x)=0$ on $[0,1]$ and $\frac{1}{x}$ for $x\in (1,\infty)$. Then we have
$$
|f|_{2}^{2}=\int^{\infty}_{1}\frac{1}{x^{2}}dx=-\frac{1}{x}|^{\infty}_{1}=1<\infty, |f|_{1}=\int^{\infty}_{1}\frac{1}{x}dx=\log[x]|^{\infty}_{1}=\log[\infty]=\infty
$$
On the other hand we may let $n=2$. If we let $f=0$ on $r\in (1,\infty)$ and $r^{-\alpha}$ on $r\in [0,1]$, we have
$$
|f|_{1}\sim \int^{1}_{0}r^{-\alpha}rdr,|f|_{2}^{2}\sim \int^{1}_{0}r^{-2\alpha}rdr
$$
We want that
$$
0<1-\alpha<1, 1-2\alpha<0
$$
This means
$$
\frac{1}{2}<\alpha<1
$$
and any $\alpha$ in this range should suffice. I am unable to construct an example for $n=1$, but I think this should be possible in principle.

Answer (score 0):

For the second one, we can use $\mathbb{R}$ with the counting measure and let $f(n)=1/n$ for positive integral $n$ and $0$ otherwise.  It should be clear that this does the trick.

Comment: No. If $f$ is $L^2$, then $f^2$ is $L^1$, as you just wrote. But this does not imply that $f$ is $L^1$.